# Move multiple-choice cursors back and forth on multiple lines in Notepad++

Tags: notepad++

In notepad++, when I do a multiple choice, for example "characters" string, I want to **move** the cursor back and forth to modify the content on multiple lines. However, the cursor only focuses on the last selection, e.g. "characters" string at Line 6.

[image]

Does anyone know how to do this action by the same way [Sublime Text](https://www.sublimetext.com/) can do ?

Or Is any notepad++ plugin able to do this action ?

Answer (score 0):

- In Settings - Preferences - Edititing enable "Mutli-Editing Settings".
- Then Ctrl + Mouse click the places where you need your cursors. Do not select the whole words.
- After you placed your cursors you can move them back and forth, write text, or delete characters. Even Ctrl+Z is working.

Comment: I knew this. But manual clicks for choices take very much time.

Answer (score 0):

At least you can go back and forward word by word once. I dont know multiple words at a time.

Backward: CTRL+Left arrow.
Forward: CTRL+Right arrow.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow where answering questions is appreciated, but please read the question first. This question is about multiple cursors moving simultaneously, it is not about word movements with one cursor. Hence this information is not useful. Please take the [tour] and read the [help] to learn about how to contribute to this site.